# ffmpeg Muxing Recovered Files - Audio dropping

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mux

A few years ago, we accidentally deleted all our home movies. We recovered the files from the camera. They have lost their headers and are not playable. I have used a recovery program (recover_mp4) to get an h264 and aac file.

When I try to mux these together, the audio drops off from the stream. It also crackles badly at times. If I play the AAC file by itself, it sounds fine. For some movies, the audio works for a while, on others it drops out quickly.

One thing I noticed is that the resulting muxed mp4 file is often shorter than the audio.

I've tried various ffmpeg commands that look generally like this:

`ffmpeg -r 30000/1001 -i recovered_video.h264 -i recovered_audio -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4`

Any ideas on how to marry the two files together?

Comment: you are alread "marrying" the files with your ffmpeg command. If you are actually asking how to synchronize them, i fear you need to syncrhonize each and every single clip... Whats your actual question?

Comment: Yes, agreed - they are together @Harry. I'm trying to find out why the ffmpeg command drops the audio from the mp4 after a few seconds. It's not that it's out of sync - it completely disappears after a few seconds. The AAC audio is fine. I'm wondering if it has something to do with an error about SSR.